# Django Assigning ID from Count: Avoiding Race Condition

Tags: django

I have a simple web app with posts and comments.

For each commenter on a post I want to assign them an identifier based on the number of distinct commenters that have come before them (commenter 1, commenter 2 ect.)

This is my initial attempt:

```
comment = Comment.objects.create(**data)
comment.user_identifier = comment.post.comments.distinct('author').count() + 1
comment.save()
```

which  works but leads to a race condition where if two comments are created simultaneously they have the same identifier. What's the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is basically a duplicate

[Avoiding race conditions, Django + Heroku + PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108984/avoiding-race-conditions-django-heroku-postgresql?rq=1)

so generally you have to use `.select_for_update()` to avoid the problem

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate, you should flag/vote to close the question.